# xhtml2pdf not picking image

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

i am creating pdf from html and it gets converted but without image. i have tried the absolute urls also but it still doesn't work
pdf function:

```
def test_pdf(request):

    template = get_template('../templates/index.html')
    html = template.render(Context(data))
    filename = 'pdfs/'+str(random.random())+'.pdf'

    file = open(filename, "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file, encoding='utf-8',link_callback=link_callback)
    # Return PDF document through a Django HTTP response
    file.seek(0)
    pdf = file.read()
    file.close()            # Don't forget to close the file handle
    return HttpResponse({"success":"success"})

def link_callback(uri, rel):

    sUrl = settings.STATIC_URL      # Typically /static/
    sRoot = settings.STATIC_ROOT    # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
    mUrl = settings.MEDIA_URL       # Typically /static/media/
    mRoot = settings.MEDIA_ROOT     # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/


    if uri.startswith(mUrl):
        path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))

    elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
        path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))

    else:
        return uri  # handle absolute uri (ie: http://some.tld/foo.png)

    if not os.path.isfile(path):
            raise Exception(
                'media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl)
            )
    return path
```

settings file :

```
PROJECT_ROOT = "/var/www/html/newclone/userapi/" 
MEDIA_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'static-root')
STATIC_URL =  "/static/"
```

What is wrong in this. pdf is generated successfully but the images are missing

html file :

```
<div class="h1"><img src="/media/xyz"></div>
```

Comment: This is not a real answer however I have used django-xhtml2pdf to render pdfs with django with great success (https://github.com/chrisglass/django-xhtml2pdf) and have also written a rather extensive blog post  about exactly that (http://spapas.github.io/2015/11/27/pdf-in-django/)... For your problem, it is probably related to the absolute img src you have there -- try using the {% static %} tag for that (or get the url of the content if it is media).

Comment: @Serafeim Have already read those links. link_callback function reads the media and replace the url so how the keyword {% static %} would help ??

Answer (score 0):

Could not even imagine the error :
in my css i have written :

```
.main{width:75%;}
```

because of this images were not visible. I just removed it randomly and images started displaying